# replace an array object in component state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

My goal is to map over an array and replace objects that match a condition. Much like this working example:

```js
const rows = [{
  "name": "Dad",
  "car": "Sedan"
}, {
  "name": "Mom",
  "car": "Sedan"
}]
const newCar = {
  "name": "Dad",
  "car": "Minivan"
}

const newArray = rows.map((r) => (r.name === newCar.name ? newCar : r))
console.log(newArray)
```

In my use case, component state contains the array, which is populated from an API.

```
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([])
```

Later, a change is required to one object in the array. The `data` variable contains the modified object to be merged into the array. I map over the array looking for matches on the `_id` field. When the `_id` matches, I return the object from `data` (the value to be merged into the array). When there is not a match, I return the object as it originally existed in state.

```
        setRows((rows) => [
          ...rows,
          rows.map((r) => (r._id === data._id ? data : r)),
        ])
```

The **desired outcome** is an array of the same size as the original. This new array should contain one modified object in addition to all original array values.

The **actual results** from the code above are that the modified `data` object is **added** rather than updated.

How can I change my code to **replace** the modified array element instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `useState()` [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) form calls a function and passes it the previous state. The `Array.map()` function returns a **new** array with the updated values. This means that you only need to map the previous state to get a new state:

```
setRows(rows => rows.map((r) => (r._id === data._id ? data : r)))
```